# Assertion of response body datetime in Postman

Tags: testing, postman

I’m new to writing Tests in Postman and below is what I’m not able to get through after spending couple of days researching. I’ll appreciate the expertise:

Following steps I have done so far. From POST request response I parse it to grab Epoch time and then convert that into human readable date time.

Response Body:
1604448930
Tue Nov 03 2020 18:15:30 GMT-0600 (Central Standard Time)

Below is what I have in Tests script:

```
jsonData = JSON.parse(responseBody)
x = jsonData[0].ScheduledAttempt.ScheduledDateTime;

epochScheduledDateTime = jsonData[0].ScheduledAttempt.ScheduledDateTime
console.log(epochScheduledDateTime)

Date = new Date ((epochScheduledDateTime) *1000);
console.log(Date)
```

Now how can I compare my human readable date to the expected min and max datetime.

For eg: Tue Nov 03 2020 18:15:30 GMT-0600 (Central Standard Time) is between
Tue Nov 03 2020 18:00:00 GMT-0600 (Central Standard Time) and
Tue Nov 03 2020 20:00:00 GMT-0600 (Central Standard Time).

Appreciate your guidance.
Thank You
Kp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you don't have to convert the epoch time to dateString, instead you can convert other datestrings and the epoch time to millisecond using the getTime() method of the Date.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getTime

> Return Value: A Number, representing the number of milliseconds since
> midnight January 1, 1970

Now you can use the chai expect method "within" to validate if the value is within the range specified

```
pm.test("Validate date to be within the expected date range", function () {

    epochScheduledDateTime = 1604448930

    

    valueGot = 1604448930 * 1000 

    pm.expect(valueGot).to.be.within((new Date("Tue Nov 03 2020 18:00:00 GMT-0600 (Central Standard Time)")).getTime(), (new Date("Tue Nov 03 2020 20:00:00 GMT-0600 (Central Standard Time)")).getTime());

})
```

Or compare dates:

```
pm.test("Validate date to be within the expected date range", function () {

      pm.expect(new Date((epochScheduledDateTime) * 1000)).to.be.within((new Date("Tue Nov 2 2020 18:00:00 GMT-0600 (Central Standard Time)")), (new Date("Tue Nov 03 2020 20:00:00 GMT-0600 (Central Standard Time)")));

 })
```

postman expect class is from chai and all chai bdd assertions are supported:

https://www.chaijs.com/api/bdd/

Comment: Thank @PDHide - second compare dates works nicely for me.

Comment: If I want to test by iterations can I do that? I have 4 iterations and each of them give different dates.

Comment: I was able to find pm.info.iteration and it works great. Thank you.